# How to stop floating div from wrapping to the next line - Tried everything

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck with this div in the header wrapping to the next line when the window is resized. You can view it at http://www.commexfx.com . The right div in the header which includes the search box etc is wrapped to the next line when resizing the window. I tried everything: changing position, display, white-space, etc, but nothing. the structure is like this:

```
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo"> </div>
      <div class="top-widget"></div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS code for the time being is:

```
#header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* max-width: 960px; */
  width: 960px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap !important; 
}


#logo {
  float: left;
  z-index: 9999999;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 360px;
  display: inline;
  border:1px solid green;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}


.top-widget {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  /*clear: right;*/
  float: right;
  height: 95px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 590px !important;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Would appreciate any help. Also searched the forums here and tried every possible solution I could find but nothing.

Thanks

Comment: What browser is it wrapping in?  I just tried viewing it in Chrome, and it doesn't wrap for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-width:960px` to your css `#header` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with these new ones.  Floating two elements, one right and one left will make them wrap so I would use inline-block.

You don't need position:relative unless you are positioning elements within that div as absolute so you can remove those as well. Same with z-index.

Also, you don't need !important unless you have other styles overriding this. I try and use it sparingly.

```
#header {
margin:0 auto;
width:960px;
}

#logo {
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 360px;
display: inline-block;
}

#logo img {
vertical-align: inherit;
}

.top-widget {
text-align: right;
width: 570px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. Can you vote this up and check it as the answer?